# Error when installing packages in RStuduio

Tags: r, install.packages

I know this question has already been asked but none of the previous answers have worked for me. I have installed RStudio (Version 1.1.463) without any problems but I can't seem to install any packages. 
So far I have tried changing CRAN Mirror both from "Tools"->"Global Options"->"Packages" and from "Preferences"->"Packages", it changed but my error still persists. 
I also tried with:

```
r = getOption("repos")
r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.rstudio.com/"
options(repos=r)
install.packages("readxl", dependencies= TRUE)
```

The error I'm getting is:
`Error in install.packages : Line starting '<html> ...' is malformed!`

I tried also `verbose = TRUE`.

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try `https`?

Comment: Doesn't work, it says: `Error in install.packages : cannot open this connection`

Comment: That's quite strange, it seems like requests from your R session are blocked with some network rules. Can you e.g. run `GET("http://cran.rstudio.com")` in your R console and get some output?

Comment: It gives me: `Error in get("http://cran.rstudio.com") : object "http://cran.rstudio.com" not found`

Comment: @G.C Yeah, well, you need to use all capital letters: `GET("http://cran.rstudio.com")`, with small `get` it won't work.

Comment: I tried small `get` because with `GET` I got: `Error: not finding function "GET"`. I am sorry, I am really new at this and I don't really know what I am doing wrong (yet).

Comment: @G.C Don't worry, that's OK, your problem is really strange, I am curious what's wrong. Could you please try to run `curlGetHeaders("http://cran.r-project.org")` from your R console then? That's from base R, so it should run even if you don't have any package installed. Please, let me know what's the result. Thanks! I hope we'll figure it out.

Comment: Still no luck: `Error in curlGetHeaders("http://cran.r-project.org") : curlGetHeaders is not supported on this platform`. I am starting to loose hope about it, maybe I will have to ask my Professor directly, I don't want to waste anymore of your time.

Comment: @G.C Sounds like some official workstation, I'd ask your system admin.